# Code for adding doubles within a text file? Java

Tags: java, file, text

I was wondering if the following code returns a sum of all the doubles in a text file. It seems to always appear as 0.0 when I test run it. What could be the problem? I

```
public double honorsCalculation() throws IOException {
    Scanner test = new Scanner(new File("Calculus - Test.txt"));
    while (test.hasNext()) {
        ArrayList <Double> assignments = new ArrayList <Double> ();
        double num = test.nextDouble();
        assignments.add(num);
        for (int i = 1; i < assignments.size() - 1; i++) {
            sum = sum + assignments.get(i);
            percentage = sum;
        }
    }
    return percentage;
}
```

Comment: Please also share an example of the file("Calculus - Test.txt")

Comment: 0.57
0.89
0.89
0.97
0.96
-1.0

Comment: I was trying to add everything after the first element and abvoid the final element

Comment: I would suggest you to debug your code (step by step) in an IDE(like netbeans, eclipse). With that, you should be able to see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating the information before reading all the data.

```
public double honorsCalculation() throws IOException {
    Scanner test = new Scanner(new File("Calculus - Test.txt"));
    ArrayList <Double> assignments = new ArrayList <Double> ();
    while (test.hasNext()) {
        double num = test.nextDouble();
        assignments.add(num);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < assignments.size() - 1; i++) {
        sum = sum + assignments.get(i);
        percentage = sum;
    }
    return percentage;
}
```

This should be the correct approach.

Comment: This ran, but I still don't understand why you would have to split the while and for loop?

Comment: On the `while` you are reading the text file, and storing each double on your `ArrayList`. On the for, you are iterating that list to do your calculation. You can't loop the array before inserting all the data on it. Otherwise you would be reading it each time you add a new value.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ArrayList` at all, and it's hard to see how a percentage can be equal to a sum, or where your variables are being initialized:

```
public double honorsCalculation() throws IOException {
    double sum = 0;
    Scanner test = new Scanner(new File("Calculus - Test.txt"));
    while (test.hasNext()) {
        sum += test.nextDouble();
    }
    return sum;
}
```